# Is it a good idea to use an OpenPGP key that has no password?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, file-encryption

I'm tarballing and compressing backup files of my system configuration, and other important stuff. The process of tarballing, compressing and encrypting happens every time [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) changes something in my backup folder, which means inserting the password of my personal GnuPG when I want to encrypt the tarball file to, well, myself.

I want to know if doing encryption of files in this way is safe and don't represent a security risk for my files.

This is how I'm currently encrypting files to myself:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

UBICACION=/home/jorge/respaldo/configuracion\ del\ sistema
chown jorge "$UBICACION/respaldos.tar.7z"
# lo ciframos
DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u jorge -- gpg --no-tty -z 0 --no-greeting --encrypt --sign --yes --local-user elcorreo@deshackra.com -r elcorreo@deshackra.com "$UBICACION/respaldos.tar.7z"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Encryption does not require the private key

First of all, *encryption* does not require the password of the private key, encryption is peformed using the (unprotected) public key. The operation requiring the private key's passphrase is *signing* the data, do you really require this for your backup strategy?

### Potential risks of unencrypted private keys

There is one obvious risk: if an attacker gets access to your unencrypted private key (ie. one without a password), he has immediate control over the key. If the key would have been encrypted (by a password), there would still have been the barrier of the password.

With other words: yes, this is a security risk; how large it is depends on your very specific use case, security practice and environment and can hardly be weighted by anybody but yourself.

To get a feeling whether this risk is something you want to take, consider (likely among others, this surely is no complete list):

- chances of the machine/hard drive being stolen (in case it's not reasonably encrypted anyway)
- somebody might get (physically) hold of the unlocked computer
- you share the private key by accident or software issues
- unpatched exploits in applications you use, allowing an attacker to backdoor your computer

### Use `gpg-agent`

As an alternative, consider using the GnuPG agent `gpg-agent`, which is necessary with newer versions of GnuPG anyway, and allows you to cache your passphrase for a while (the exact duration can be configured), which reduces risks heavily without including too many hassles in daily use.

Comment: I just deleted the `--sign` flag! Thank you for the answer!